# Function using AJAX throws "Unexpected Token }", Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is very abnormal. I am trying to solve this error for 3 days but it's not getting on my nerves now. So, I have a button and a textbox that submits the data in the textbox to a PHP page. There the data is stored into my database.

Here's the PHP File:

```php
if(Class_Name::Function_Name($_POST["id"], $_POST["text"])) $data["status"] = "success";
else $data["status"] = "error";

echo json_encode($data);
```

Here's the JS function:

```js
function editPostOffer(postId, offer_id, edited_content) {
    $.post("admin/post_offer/edit_post_offer.php", {id: offer_id, text: edited_content.value}, function(data) {
        if(data.status == "success") {
            window.location.href = "post.php?id="+postId;
        } else {
            console.log("A");
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

Here's the button + textarea(in the generated form):

```html
<div class="content">
    <p class="content" style="display: none;">areebaaa</p>
    <textarea class="hide span12" id="edited_content" style="display: inline-block;">areebaaa</textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="editPostOffer(" 13 ",=" " "56 ",=" " "assa ");"="" style="display: inline-block;">Save Edits</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits" style="display: inline-block;">Cancel Edits</button>
</div>
```

But the original JS creating HTML is here:

```js
var offers = <? php echo Class_Name::Function_Name($_GET["id"]); ?> ;
for (var i = 0; i < offers.length; i++) {
    var date = offers[i].Date.split(" ");
    document.write('<div class="row-fluid offer">' +
        '<div class="span2">' +
        '<img class="profile_picture" src="' + offers[i].Picture_Path + '" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="span10">' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="username">' +
        '<p style="font-weight: bold;">' + offers[i].Name + '</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="content">' +
        '<p class="content">' + offers[i].Text + '</p>' +
        '<textarea class="hide span12" id="edited_content">' + offers[i].Text + '</textarea>' +
        '<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick=' + editPostOffer("13", "56", "assa") + '>Save Edits</button>&nbsp;' +
        '<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits">Cancel Edits</button>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
        '<div class="date">' +
        '<p class="pull-right"><strong><span class="muted">Offered on: </span></strong>' + date[0] + '</p>' +
        '</div>');
    if (offers[i].Username == "<?php echo $_SESSION["
    username "]; ?>") {
        document.write('<div class="controls pull-right">' +
            '<a href="" class="no_link edit_offer">Edit</a>&nbsp;' +
            '<a href="" class="no_link" onclick="showDeleteOfferModal(' + offers[i].Offer_ID + ');">Delete</a> |&nbsp;' +
            '</div>');
    }
    document.write('</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<hr />');
}
```

I know the error is here: `.. onclick="editPostOffer(" 13 ",=" " "56 ",=" " "assa ");"=""..`.

There is a mesh up of EQUALTOS and COMMAS but I am not getting that why are they coming? Is there any way I can solve this?

**UPDATE:**

I've updated my code now the error that is only coming is that the JS is not able to find the **textarea**

```
...
'<div class="content">' +
    '<p class="content">' + offers[i].Text + '</p>' +
    '<textarea class="hide span12" id="edited_content">' + offers[i].Text + '</textarea>' +
    '<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick=\'editPostOffer("<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>","' + offers[i].Offer_ID + '","' + $("#edited_content") + '");\'>Save Edits</button>&nbsp;' +
    '<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits">Cancel Edits</button>' +
    '</div>' +
...
```

Here's the updates JS:

```
function editPostOffer(postId, offer_id, edited_content) {
    console.log(postId);
    console.log(offer_id);
    console.log(edited_content);
    $.post("admin/post_offer/edit_post_offer.php", {id: offer_id, text: edited_content.val()}, function(data) {
        if(data.status == "success") {
            window.location.href = "post.php?id="+postId;
        } else {
            console.log("A");
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

When I output the data into the console this comes up:

```
13
56
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'val'
```

The error in the last line means that the object is null and that is because the jQuery was not able to find the textarea.

Comment: I think the problem is your quotes (`"`). You need to escape them.

Comment: by running really really fast

Comment: What you want to have in the `editPostOffer` method as parameter. What is the final string because it is some big mesh there.

Comment: @tereško was that a joke? :P

Comment: @Bankin I want to have `editPostOffer("13", "56", "assa")` <-- this

Comment: why is it voted down?

Comment: try `onclick='editPostOffer("13","56","assa");'`

Comment: Then remove all the '=' and '/' - just like you wrote it `editPostOffer("13","56","assa");`

Comment: @Bankin that's the problem. The equals and commas are added automatically I don't know why. I can't remove them from my JS because they aren't present there. :(

Comment: equals and commas must be added by browser, to fix empty quotes without parameters. You should look at source code, not at Firebug or similar inspector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unclear what you want to pass to that onclick function, try using different/escaping quotes here:

```
onclick="editPostOffer(' 13 ',\'=' ' '56 '\',\'=' ' 'assa '\');"
```

or

```
onclick="editPostOffer(' 13 ',=' ' '56 ',=' ' 'assa ');"
```

**EDIT:**

after you added more code to your post I suggest this:

```
onclick="' + editPostOffer("13", "56", "assa") + '">
        ^                                         ^ //added quotes here
```

About the text area, you are passing id, so maybe you should try this:

```
{id: offer_id, text: $('#'+edited_content).val()}
```

or

```
{id: offer_id, text: document.getElementById('edited_content').value}
```

instead of

```
{id: offer_id, text: edited_content.value}
```

Comment: i've update my code. let me post it then check the new error out!

Comment: The error is now this: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'val'  :/

Comment: I have added updated JS code to the question now check that out.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, you cannot use just `edited_content.val()`, use `$('#'+edited_content).val()` or `document.getElementById('edited_content').value`;

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, did you see my update? did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS HTML creation line:

```
'<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick=' + editPostOffer("13", "56", "assa") + '>Save Edits</button>&nbsp;' +
```

to:

```
'<button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick=\'editPostOffer("13", "56", "assa")\'>Save Edits</button>&nbsp;' +
```

Comment: before you send the request, write to console your post data. On the other hand, you can debug PHP and output your post data as:
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $_POST );
    echo "</pre>";

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript when you add the onclick `onclick=' + editPostOffer("13", "56", "assa") + '>` here it is just a string no need to get it out of the string.

Try doing it like this - `onclick="editPostOffer(\"13\", \"56\", \"assa\")" >`